# SQLite field with a list of foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I am building an SQLite DB to keep my real estate agents' listings.  I have been able to use a foreign key to identify a listing for each agent, but I want to make a list of listings in each agent's record; moving from a one-to-one relationship between agents and listings to a one-to-many relationship.

Looking here: http://www.sqlite.org/draft/foreignkeys.html , there is no mention of a field that is a 'list of foreign keys'.  Is what I'm trying doable?

I considered that, as a workaround, I might make a table that contains the relationships themselves, but that doesn't seem to be a very clean solution.  I looked at this thread: [SQLite foreign key examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934994/sqlite-foreign-key-examples) , but I'm not sure that my elements are similar to the many-to-many relationship they describe there.

I am also open to suggestions on how this can be done better.  Should I just include a listing agent's name on the actual listing table and just query from there?

```
CREATE TABLE listings
(
    listing_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    listing_address   TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    acq_date          DATE
 )

CREATE TABLE agent
(
     agent_id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     agent_name       TEXT NOT NULL,
     agent_listings   INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY (agent_listings) REFERENCES listings (listing_id) NOT NULL
 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the foreign key to the `listings` table instead; for a one-to-many relationship it is the 'many' side that records the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE listings
(
    listing_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    listing_address   TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    acq_date          DATE
    agent_id          INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agent (agent_id)
)

CREATE TABLE agent
(
     agent_id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     agent_name       TEXT NOT NULL,
)
```

If you wanted listings to be handled by *multiple* agents (in a many-to-many relationship), you'll have to add a linking table:

```
CREATE TABLE listings
(
    listing_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    listing_address   TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    acq_date          DATE
)

CREATE TABLE agent
(
    agent_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    agent_name        TEXT NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE agent_listings
(
    agent_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    listing_id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (agent_id, listing_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agent (agent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (listing_id) REFERENCES listings (listing_id),
)
```

Comment: 'Link Table' were the magic words, I now understand the implementation of the relationships a lot better (Though Wikipedia seems to prefer ['Junction Tables'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)). I am now a little concerned that keeping the foreign key on this side might drastically complicate querying/delete synching, etc.

Wouldn't trying to keep, say, a listing's metatags straight be kind of a nightmare this way?

Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: This is how relational databases *work*; using foreign key relationships you can ask the database to produce subsets of the Cartesian product of two tables. Databases are generally optimized for such relationship handling already, and you'll quickly get the hang of the model.

Comment: You can look at the [foreign key actions](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) to handle cascades (deleting rows in one table triggering deletes elsewhere).