# Sqlite update not affecting all rows when using subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669789/7050476) I am trying to update a column in table `b` based on values from table `a`, where table `b` has a foreign key to table `a`. My query executes successfully and works as expected on the rows it affects. However, it does not affect all rows, and I do not understand why. It seems to only affect three rows no matter how large the database.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( qty1 INTEGER, qty2 INTEGER, aID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE b ( bID INTEGER, aID INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(aID) REFERENCES a(aID) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO a (qty1, qty2, aID) VALUES (0, 100, 1906250435150010797);

INSERT INTO a (qty1, qty2, aID) VALUES (100, 100, 1906250435150010798);

INSERT INTO a (qty1, qty2, aID) VALUES (0, 100, 1906250435150010799);

INSERT INTO b (bID, aID) VALUES (0, 1906250435150010797);

INSERT INTO b (bID, aID) VALUES (0, 1906250435150010798);

INSERT INTO b (bID, aID) VALUES (1, 1906250435150010798);

INSERT INTO b (bID, aID) VALUES (0, 1906250435150010799);

ALTER TABLE b ADD COLUMN SameQty INTEGER;

UPDATE b SET SameQty = 0 WHERE aID = (SELECT aID from a where qty1 != qty2);

UPDATE b SET SameQty = 1 WHERE aID = (SELECT aID from a where qty1 = qty2);
```

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Tested on sqlite 3.26.0

Comment: If your primary key is a single `INTEGER` column, making it a `WITHOUT ROWID` table is a very odd choice.

Comment: @Shawn Why? That column is a non-null, signed, incremental 64-bit integer. As far as I understand that's the behavior of rowid, hence I would not need a rowid. Looking at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html it seems to me that it could be redundant since a single `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column already functions as rowid.

Comment: Among other things, you lose the ability to automatically generate a value for the pk if one is left out of an insert (not a big deal if you always specify a value), and it's slower to access than a normal rowid table is (see section 4 of https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html ). `WITHOUT ROWID` works best with tables that have composite or non-integer PKs and with no or few indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update statement:

```
UPDATE b SET SameQty = 0 WHERE aID = (SELECT aID from a where qty1 != qty2);
```

has a subquery that can return multiple rows, but is used in a context where only a single row is expected. I feel like that should cause an error, but if you're not seeing one, maybe it's just picking a single arbitrary row from the results?

Anyways, you want `IN`:

```
UPDATE b SET SameQty = 0 WHERE aID IN (SELECT aID from a where qty1 != qty2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your using a subquery that can and does return more than one row in a scalar context when doing "`WHERE aID = (SELECT aID from a`". Use `IN` instead of `=`.

```
UPDATE b SET SameQty = 0 WHERE aID IN (SELECT aID from a where qty1 != qty2);
UPDATE b SET SameQty = 1 WHERE aID IN (SELECT aID from a where qty1 = qty2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=24e59d12ba9dbee30d289d41de0e26b3)