# SQLite, Golang and junction table

Tags: sql, sqlite, go, sql-insert, junction-table

I would like to create a small database of books using Go and sqlite. I took the main from this advise [SQLite foreign key examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934994/sqlite-foreign-key-examples) and redeveloped it a bit.

```
package main                                                                                                                                                

import (
    "database/sql"
...
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

...
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./foo.db")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer db.Close()

sqlStmt := `
    create table books (
        id integer primary key autoincrement, 
        title text
    );

    create table booksauthors ( 
        bookid integer references books(id), 
        uthorid integer references authors(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );

    create table authors (
        id integer primary key autoincrement, 
        fname text, 
        mname text,
        lname text,
        unique (fname, mname, lname) on conflict ignore
    );
`
```

So, I'd like to keep list of unique authors and maintain many-to-many connection with books tables (one book may have more then one author, and author might write more then one book).

Then I simply add books in cycle, get LastIndexID and put it to junction table (code is reduces for illustration, b is book struct):

```
tx, err := db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

res, err := db.Exec("Insert into books(title) values(?)", b.Title)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
b_id, _ := res.LastInsertId()
for _, a := range b.Authors {
    res, err = db.Exec("Insert into authors(fname, mname, lname) values(?, ?, ?)", a.Fname, a.Mname, a.Lname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    a_id, _ := res.LastInsertId()
    fmt.Println(a_id, b_id, a)

    res, err = db.Exec("Insert into booksauthors(bookid, authorid) values(?, ?)", b_id, a_id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
tx.Commit()
```

By here comes trouble - a_id is increased if I add more then one book of the same author, but junctions table contains older value of it.
For example:

```
Books:                       
id | Title                   
---|--------------------
1  | Atlas Shrugged pt.1 
2  | Atlas Shrugged pt.2
3  | Atlas Shrugged pt.3

Authors:
id | Fname | Mname | Lname 
---|-------|-------|------
702| Ayn   |       | Rand

Junction table:
BookId | AuthorID
-------|---------
 1     |  700
 2     |  701
 3     |  702

What I want - Junction table:
BookId | AuthorID
-------|---------
 1     |  702
 2     |  702
 3     |  702
```

How can I fix it so correct AuthorId would be reflected at the table? I don't want use GORM or any of ORM tools and trying to solve it using pure (well, more or less) SQL.

One of the solutions I see now I can first SELECT, then INSERT if nothing is found and then SELECT once again, however I'm not sure how idiomatic this idea is. Please note that I have considerable numbers of records to add.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to `SELECT` you list of authors and `INSERT` the ones that are missing. The solution is naive, but it works and is simple.
I'm not up-to-date with SQLite relationnal features, but using them isn't always the simplest wway to deal with foreign keys….

Now, if you have a big bulk of data to process, do the same operation but start by merging your books authors so you can have only one `SELECT` then one `INSERT` to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick'n'dirty hack I did a select after adding an author:

```
err = db.QueryRow("select id from authors where fname = ? and mname = ? and lname = ?", a.Fname, a.Mname, a.Lname).Scan(&a_id)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
res, err = db.Exec("Insert into booksauthors(bookid, authorid) values(?, ?)", b_id, a_id)
if err != nil {
    enter code herelog.Fatal(err)
}
```

But I'm still looking for better answer...